# How do I make a transparent clip art image render identical to how it looks in the video editor?

Tags: rendering, transparency, video-sequence-editor

[image]I added a blue flare animation to a transparent video for a client. It renders exactly how it appears in the video editor when I render it in mp4 or .mov but when I try to render in rbga (using QuickTime + qt animation), the entire animation renders perfectly except for the blue flare.

[image]

Now the entire animation is transparent which is good but now the flare looks very blown out. What setting can fix this?

I got the original transparent blue flare clip art from google images, then overlayed it over my animation using “alpha over”.